# Rails - NoMethodError (undefined method 'permit' for "reps":string)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to create multiple objects from a single form in Rails 5. This was working perfectly fine in rails 4.2, I'm not exactly sure what is causing the error (I imagine it has something to do with the view).

Another problem I've run into after upgrading to rails 5 is now my form is only submitting the last record. I used this walkthrough for reference: http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/

[This is the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bgmq.png) and 
here are the parameters I'm sending.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"3j8A0oNW3sM5VIi11ZEHwpwlAhvY3
vml1kcLHfWdptySKSeJokRmBXObh/HEFBwG4/QC8PdfX7NKbkrGjOfI6Q==", "exercise_id"=>"16
5", "exercise_sets"=>{"reps"=>"1", "weight"=>"1"}, "exerciseName"=>"imsick", "co
mmit"=>"Save changes"}
```

The Error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'permit' for "reps":string)
```

ExerciseSetsController:

```
def create
    if current_trainer
        savedMirror = current_trainer.exercises.find_by_name(params[:exerciseName])

        params['exercise_sets'].each do |set|
            #set[:timeFormat] = savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].timeFormat
            #set[:weightFormat] = savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].weightFormat
            #set[:distanceFormat] = savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].distanceFormat
            ExerciseSet.create(exercise_set_params(set))
        end

        flash[:notice] = "Sets added"
        redirect_to (:back)
    end
end

private 
def exercise_set_params(e_params)
  e_params.permit(:id, :reps, :weight, :weightFormat, :time, :timeFormat, :distance, :distanceFormat, :exercise_id, :_destroy)
end
```

View:

```
<%savedMirror = current_trainer.exercises.find_by_name(e.name)%>
<%= form_tag  url_for(controller: "exercise_sets", action: "create") do%>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <% e.sets.times do |i|%>
        <%= fields_for "exercise_sets[]", @exerciseSet do |f| %>
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <label>Set: <%=i+1%></label>
                <%#= f.number_field :user_id, value: e.user_id, style:"visibility:hidden; margin:-15px;"%>
                <%= hidden_field_tag(:exercise_id, e.id) %>

              <div class = "row">
                <% if savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].reps == 1%>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <%= f.label :reps, "Reps" %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :reps, class: "form-control"%>
                  </div>
                <%end%>
                <% if savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].weight == 1%>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <%= f.label :weight, "Weight" %><br>
                      <%= f.text_field :weight, class: "form-control"%>
                  </div>
                <%end%>
                <% if savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].time == 1%>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <%= f.label :time, "Time" %><br>
                      <%= f.text_field :time, class: "form-control"%>
                  </div>
                <%end%>
                <% if savedMirror.exercise_sets[0].distance == 1%>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <%= f.label :distance, "Distance" %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :distance, class: "form-control"%>
                  </div>
                <%end%>
              </div>
        </li>
        <%end%>
        <%end%>
        <br>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:exerciseName, e.name) %>
        <%=submit_tag%>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you make an answer with the changes you made to the Rails code instead, and mark it as an answer one day after ?

Comment: Good point, posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem:

I was not passing the values as a hash, instead I was passing them as an array. I fixed it by changing the individual fields to:

```
<input type="text" name="exercise_sets[][reps]" class="form-control" />

<input type="text" name="exercise_sets[][weight]" class="form-control" />
```

... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.require(:exercise)` (I am assuming your model's name is exercise) to use strong params.

Requiring will enable your app to give error if you don't pass the model. Because the parameters you are whitelisting are defined for that model.

Just replace

```
def exercise_set_params(e_params)
  e_params.permit(:id, :reps, :weight, :weightFormat, :time, :timeFormat, :distance, :distanceFormat, :exercise_id, :_destroy)
end
```

**with**

```
def exercise_set_params(e_params)
  e_params.require(:exercise).permit(:id, :reps, :weight, :weightFormat, :time, :timeFormat, :distance, :distanceFormat, :exercise_id, :_destroy)
end
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks for help! Unfortunately I now get this error:

NoMethodError (private method 'require' called for "reps":string)

I believe it has something to do with the format of the parameters i'm submitting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `:reps`, *and `:weight`*, are passed as nested params like this

```
"exercise_sets"=>{"reps"=>"1", "weight"=>"1"}
```

So I would be tempted to try this:

```
e_params.permit(:id, exercise_sets: [:reps, :weight], :weightFormat, :time, :timeFormat, :distance, :distanceFormat, :exercise_id, :_destroy)
```

Note the nesting:

```
exercise_sets: [:reps, :weight]
```

Maybe that will do it.

Comment: You didn't read the code. `params['exercise_sets'].each do |set| ... exercise_set_params(set)` so the `e_params` are already a parameter object that should contain only the nested keys in question.

Comment: yup, my bad, looks like the fella solved his problem anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i had the same problem send data for ajax with axios in params, the solution was added values in "data" instead "params"

```
axios({
        method:'patch',
        url:'/clients/'+ item +'/update.json',
        //params:{'client': {'info': info}},
        data:{authenticity_token:token,client:{info: info}},
        responseType:'json'
    })
```